# gnuplot not allowing to plot simple file saying invalid next size

Tags: plot, gnuplot

When I am trying to plot a file Gnuplot automatically quits saying "malloc(): invalid next size (unsorted) \n Aborted". I am not able to understand what is happening. Please help

```
G N U P L O T
Version 5.2 patchlevel 6    last modified 2019-01-01 

Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2018
Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others

gnuplot home:     http://www.gnuplot.info
faq, bugs, etc:   type "help FAQ"
immediate help:   type "help"  (plot window: hit 'h')

Terminal type is now 'qt'
gnuplot> plot "L1000_N100000_ten_av100_binten_1.50.dat" 
malloc(): invalid next size (unsorted)
Aborted
```

Comment: Now, It is working if I reduce the length of file name to 31 characters or below(i.e "L1000_N100000_ten_av100_bin.dat ). why there is such a limit?

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: @fahd Using your filename, I don't have any problem under Windows 8.1 x64.

Comment: @maij debian 10